# Passing C# List to X++

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

In C# Project in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 AOT I have a method which returns List and I wanted to refer to this method in X++ code.

My initial thought was that it should be easy. Something like: `List XppProjectList = cSharpGetProjectList.GetStringList();`. However, that didn't worked.

After extensive research on Internet I found out, that I could use `System.Collections.ArrayList` instead of `List` and this time it works, but only with a single dimension collections.

X++ code that's supposed to consume C# collection:

```
public void GetProjectList()
{
    cSharpGetProjectList = new PS2010Service.CSharpGetProjectList();

    projectList = cSharpGetProjectList.GetStringList();

    length = projectList.get_Count();
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        info(projectList.get_Item(i));
    }
}
```

C# method returning `List<T>` which **works**:

```
public static List<String> GetStringList()
{
    List<String> list = new List<String>();
    list.Add("One");
    list.Add("Two");
    list.Add("Three");

    return list;
}
```

C# method returning `ArrayList` which also **works**:

```
public static ArrayList GetStringList()
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.Add("One");
    list.Add("Two");
    list.Add("Three");

    return list;
}
```

C# method returning multidimensional `ArrayList` which **doesn't work**:

```
public ArrayList GetStringList()
{

    ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
    list1.Add("One");
    list1.Add("Two");
    list1.Add("Three");

    ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
    list2.Add("1");
    list2.Add("2");
    list2.Add("3");

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new string[] { list1[i].ToString(), list2[i].ToString() });
    }

    return list;
}
```

Error returned is: 
*Clr Interop Marshal: Unsupported type.
Error executing code: Global (object), method info called with invalid parameters.*
Although it can read the length of this `ArrayList` and returns 3.

Same goes for multidimensional `List<T>` which I won't post here to make question shorter.

So my question is - how to consume C#'s multidimensional List in X++ code? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your return value from .NET is `ArrayList` with `string[2]` elements.

Code should look like this:

```csharp
System.Collections.ArrayList result = cSharpGetProjectList.GetStringList();
System.String[] netEmement;

str val1, val2;
int i;

for (i=0; i < result.get_Count(); i++)
{
    netEmement = result.get_Item(i);
    val1 = netEmement.get_Item(0);
    val2 = netEmement.get_Item(1);
}
```

Instead of *for* you could also use *Enumerator*:

```csharp
System.Collections.IEnumerator netEnumerator = result.GetEnumerator();
while (netEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    netEmement = netEnumerator.get_Current();
    val1 = netEmement.get_Item(0);
    val2 = netEmement.get_Item(1);
}
```